# JFrame getLocation and setLocation deal with system border differently

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating a multi-user Swing GUI application, and want the user's window location and size settings to persist when they log out and back in. I am currently getting the window location and size using the `getLocation()` and `getSize()` methods on my parent JFrame when the user logs out and saving them to a file, and then when the user logs back in I read those values back in and set the window size and location using `setLocation()` and `setSize()`.

The problem that I am having is that `getLocation()` and `getSize()` appear to be subtracting off the system border (e.g. if I put the window in the upper left corner `getLocation` returns `(1,54)` instead of `(0,0)`), but `setLocation()` and `setSize()` don't. The result is that every time I logout and log back in, the window appears slightly offset and slightly smaller than it did when I closed it.

Does anybody know why this might be happening or how I can get around it? Is there some other method I should be using to get and set the window location and size?

I'm running java 1.7.0_45 on Ubuntu 12.04, if that helps.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The following example replicates the issue I am seeing:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class JFrameTest
{
  private JFrame frame; 
  private JButton button;

  private Point lastLocation;
  private Dimension lastSize;

  private void run()
  {
    button = new JButton("Test");
    button.addActionListener(listener);

    lastLocation = new Point(0, 0);
    lastSize = new Dimension(200, 200);

    initFrame();
  }

  private void initFrame()
  {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().add(button);

    frame.setLocation(lastLocation);
    frame.setPreferredSize(lastSize);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private ActionListener listener = new ActionListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      if (e.getSource() == button)
      {
        lastLocation = frame.getLocationOnScreen();
        lastSize = frame.getSize();

        frame.dispose();

        initFrame();
      }
    }
  };

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run()
      {
        new JFrameTest().run();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Also, I see the same issue when I use `getLocationOnScreen()` instead of `getLocation()`.

Comment: An actually [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: if you use `setLocationByPlattform(true)` i think that in ubuntu put the screen in 0,0 top right

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I included a runnable example that replicates my problem; thanks for the suggestion. @nachokk - Thanks for the feedback, but calling `frame.setLocationByPlatform(true)` in the example code above doesn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: I'm going to give a +1 just for that awesome example!  Nice.  While completely useless for you, it works on Windows...might be a bug somewhere...

Comment: You should `pack()` _before_ you `setLocation()`.

Comment: @peeskillet Why?  The OP is setting the frames size, how would `pack` (or `setSize`) effect the location of the frame?  Only asking

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're right, I was thinking in my head of the times where I'd accidently put the locationrelativeto null before the pack and the frame wouldnt be in the middle. But with setlocation it doesn't seem to have that problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use getLocationOnScreen()

> Gets the location of this component in the form of a point specifying
>   the component's top-left corner in the screen's coordinate space.

Comment: And `getContentPane().getSize();` / `setSize()` for handling dimensions.

Comment: This might work on Ubuntu, but a windows "location" is the location on the screen, it has no other context to be located within...just saying...