# Windows alignment in SWING-based GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

My goal is to display several views of one object. For each view I create a thread. Also, I have a class which controls those views, e.g. send a command to align them. However, it is not always I get correct alignment. So there is a data races, and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Here there is a piece of code showing the problem I have. It has a simple idea: create a main view window, and then align the second window of the same size near its right border.

First, I have an abstract class to create a thread:

```
public abstract class ViewWindow implements Runnable{

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean terminate = false ;

    private Controller controller;

    private UpdateTask currentUpdateTask = null;

    private class UpdateTask {
        boolean alignWindows = true;
    }

    public ViewWindow(Controller controller, String title) {
        this.title = title;
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public void startThread() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        UpdateTask updateTask = null;

        synchronized (thread) {
            while (terminate == false) {
                try {
                    thread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                updateTask = currentUpdateTask;
                currentUpdateTask = null;

                if(updateTask.alignWindows) {
                    controller.getLock().lock();
                    setLocationRelativeTo(controller.getMainWindow());
                    controller.getLock().unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void alignWindowsUsingThread() {
        synchronized (thread) {
            currentUpdateTask = new UpdateTask();
            thread.notify();
        }
    }

    public abstract void setLocationRelativeTo(ImageViewWindow imageWindow);
}
```

Then I extend it to create an abstraction for the window views:

```
public abstract class ImageViewWindow extends ViewWindow {

    private JFrame frame;

    public ImageViewWindow(Controller controller, String title) {
        super(controller, title);

        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(title);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    synchronized public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
        frame.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    synchronized public Point getLocation() {
        return frame.getLocation();
    }
}
```

Finally, I override a function to set relative location for each window:

```
public class FirstWindow extends ImageViewWindow {

    public FirstWindow(Controller controller, String title) {
        super(controller, title);

        this.setLocation(50, 50);
        this.startThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocationRelativeTo(ImageViewWindow imageWindow) { }
}


public class SecondWindow extends ImageViewWindow {

    public SecondWindow(Controller controller, String title) {
        super(controller, title);
        this.startThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocationRelativeTo(ImageViewWindow imageWindow) {
        Point location = imageWindow.getLocation();

        int xOffSet = imageWindow.getFrame().getWidth();
        int yOffSet = 0;

        this.setLocation(xOffSet + location.x, yOffSet + location.y);
    }
}
```

Here there is a class which is responsible for the control:

```
public class Controller {

    private Lock controlLock;

    private List<ImageViewWindow> windows = new ArrayList<ImageViewWindow>();

    private ImageViewWindow mainWindow;

    public Controller() {
        controlLock =  new ReentrantLock();
    }

    public ImageViewWindow getMainWindow() {
        return mainWindow;
    }

    public Lock getLock() {
        return controlLock;
    }

    public void addMainWindow(ImageViewWindow mainViewWindow) {
        this.mainWindow = mainViewWindow;
        this.addWindow(mainViewWindow);
    }

    public void addWindow(ImageViewWindow imageWindow) {
        windows.add(imageWindow);
    }

    public void updateWindowPositions() {
        for(ImageViewWindow window : windows) {
            window.alignWindowsUsingThread();
        }
    }
}
```

And do run everything:

```
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Controller controller = new Controller();

        ImageViewWindow window1 = new FirstWindow(controller, "FirstWindow");
        controller.addMainWindow(window1);

        ImageViewWindow window2 = new SecondWindow(controller, "SecondWindow");
        controller.addWindow(window2);

        controller.updateWindowPositions();
    }
}
```

**UPD:** I updated the code based on the answer below, but the problem still remains!

Comment: Wild guess: Since each thread aligns one view (A) based on another view's (B) position, the view B may be aligned *after* view A. This can lead to a wrongly aligned B.

Comment: Hmm... But the view I use to align other views has a predefined position, and it doesn't change. I set its value before I start its thread. So I am not sure it is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t specify how you want to “align” your windows but from your code

```
public void setLocationRelativeTo(ImageViewWindow imageWindow) {
    Point location = imageWindow.getLocation();

    int xOffSet = this.getFrame().getWidth();
    int yOffSet = 0;

    this.setLocation(xOffSet + location.x, yOffSet + location.y);
}
```

I suppose you want `this` to be placed to the right of `imageWindow`. In this case you have to use `imageWindow.x + imageWindow.width` rather than `imageWindow.x + this.width`:

```
| imageWindow | this
x ← width   → x ← width →
              ↳=imageWindow.x+imageWindow.width
```

So the correct method would be:

```
public void setLocationRelativeTo(ImageViewWindow imageWindow) {
    Point location = imageWindow.getLocation();

    int xOffSet = imageWindow.getFrame().getWidth();
    int yOffSet = 0;

    this.setLocation(xOffSet + location.x, yOffSet + location.y);
}
```

By the way, I don’t get why you are making such a simple task that complicated and even multi-threaded. There’s no benefit from multi-threading here, only a complication that obstructs the view on the simplest things…

Comment: Thank you for you reply! Actually it is a baby example to show the problem I have. With a current update task I would like to pass much more information. Basically, I would like to send parameters to rerender different views, while the main thread is continuing to do some computing. In my original code I didn't have this mistake with 'this'. And it still works correctly in only about 50% of runs. Also, in my real code I use 'ImageWindow' (which is derived from 'Frame') class from ImageJ, and I get a constant offset in window position. Even if I do it without any additional multithreading.

Comment: Here it is explained the problem with offsets I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074312/jframe-getlocation-and-setlocation-deal-with-system-border-differently# But it seems there is no solution...